# ObjectMapper: Using reflection in map function

Tags: ios, swift, reflection, objectmapper

I am using `ObjectMapper` for a while and I find it cumbersome to write map function for classes with lots of property by using the way described in documents:

```
func mapping(map: Map) {
    username    <- map["username"]
    age         <- map["age"]
    weight      <- map["weight"]
    array       <- map["array"]
    dictionary  <- map["dictionary"]
    bestFriend  <- map["bestFriend"]
    friends     <- map["friends"]
}
```

I wonder if it is possible to use reflection to write map function like below assuming my JSON data and my class have axactly same property names:

```
func mapping(map: Map) {
    let names = Mirror(reflecting: self).children.flatMap { $0.label }
    for name in names {
        self.value(forKey: name) <- map[name]
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Based on Sweeper's answer I have updated my code:

```
func mapping(map: Map) {
    for child in Mirror(reflecting: self).children.compactMap({$0}) {
        child <- map[child.label]
    }
}
```

I guess this should work.

**UPDATE 2:**

Thanks to Sweeper, I have find out my initial guess was wrong and `Child` is just a typealias for a touple:

```
public typealias Child = (label: String?, value: Any)
```

So my second attempt is also won't work.

Comment: Are you aware that in Swift 4 you can use `Codable` and it handles everything for you in your specific situation?

Comment: I know about `Codable` but ObjectMapper provides more features so I prefer to only use it.

Comment: I prefer https://github.com/Ahmed-Ali/JSONExport to create Mappable swift classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<-` operator is declared like this:

```
public func <- <T: RawRepresentable>(left: inout T, right: Map) {
    left <- (right, EnumTransform())
}
```

As you can see, the left parameter is declared `inout`. This means that you must use a mutable variable there, not the return value of some method.

So you do need to write all the properties.

I found this plugin that generates the mapping for you: https://github.com/liyanhuadev/ObjectMapper-Plugin

In Swift 4, `Codable` is introduced and yet automatically works things out for you:

```
struct Foo: Codable {
    var username: String
    var age: Int
    var weight: Double

    // everything is done for you already! You don't need to write anything else
}
```

Comment: @OlcayErtaş I doubt that works either... Does it? `child` is just a copy of the actual property. Mutating it doesn't affect the actual property.

Comment: So in Swift reflection, there is no way to get actual property by name rigth?

Comment: @OlcayErtaş You can get the property's value by name, but to change the value of the property is hard. I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31589405/using-reflection-to-set-object-properties-without-using-setvalue-forkey You can probably make that work with Object Mapper, but it's _really_ fragile and ugly. You kind of lose the whole point of using Object Mapper.