# Swift 5.7, can you use a string to dynamically use a keyPath with Structs?

Tags: swift, codable, swift-structs

```
struct Server: Codable {
 let cats: Int
 let dogs: Int
 let fishies: Int
}
```

It must be `Codable`.

```
let x = Server(cats: 42, dogs: 13, fishes: 777)
```

We can use keypaths:

```
print( x[keyPath: \.dogs] )
```

Which would print "13".

Is there a way to use a string for the keypath? So, something like

```
let str = ".dogs"
print( x[ keyPath: \$str ] ]
```

or perhaps

```
let s = ".dogs"
let k = KeyPath(fromString: s)
print( x[keyPath: k] )
```

---

*(Note, I appreciate there are any number of other approaches, eg, use sql, dictionaries, switch statement, etc etc. The question at hand is as stated, TY)*

Comment: KeyPaths are related to what you're looking for, but not quite the same.

Comment: 1) Why? and 2) What has this to do with KVO? Do you actually mean KVC?Yes, as mentioned by jnpdx go for KeyPath

Comment: I'm not really sure that it answers your question, though -- they are read only, for example. Feel free to add your own answer, though, if you feel that it fits your use-case.

Comment: @Fattie related  https://stackoverflow.com/a/46597941/2303865

Comment: You can probably achieve what you want adding a setter as well to the dictionary property.

Comment: You can add a subscript to your struct.

Comment: @LeoDabus sure there are many other approaches.

Comment: Look at my answer with an approach how set/get properties of class/structs by a string keypath: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31589405/using-reflection-to-set-object-properties-without-using-setvalue-forkey/71967586#71967586

Comment: amazing stuff @iUrii it's a real mess doing it with reflection - but ytou did it!!!! bravo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Swift 5.7, can you use a **string** to dynamically use a keyPath with Structs?

For the record, the answer is **No**, you cannot, as of Swift5.

---

If you need to access struct fields, by string (for example in a typical "column definition" setup), just IMO the best thing to do is simply something like ...

```
func structField(viaString key: String) -> String {
    switch key {
    case "height": return String(self.height)
    case "lat": return self.lat
    case "long": return self.long
    ... etc
    ... etc
```

which would vary in your use case.

Comment: I'd like to ask again what is the purpose? One of the most essentials goals of Swift is type safety and *key-value coding* with string literals runs contrary to that..

Comment: Cheers @vadian for sure. An everyday example is when you have or get something like a "columns definition file". So you're laying out 1000s pieces of data in dozens of columns. It would be insane to program the columns adhoc, so you have some sort of internal say settings file (perhaps json or csv), or indeed, frequently that comes dynamically from your cloud. So if column 38 is "heading, 'Persons', data houses ownerid field to owners headcount field" you need to be able to parse the string "headcount" to someStruct.headcount

Comment: { I find these days I rarely am putting together apps which have any let's say "direct" elements, processes, layouts. Everything is generalized and "tools driven" it seems. }

Comment: PS *"string literals runs contrary to that.."* I don't see the slightest issue with that, the way I'm looking at it.  If there's some sort of "tooling system instruction" that means "here, use the field .catCount" then internal to the app, like in "my programming," the property .catCount can only be used correctly.  {Indeed, this is why it's so much better than, when, say someone is sending in freeform sql or something, of course then you're completely subject to not so much attacks but your colleague upstream completely screwing up and crashing the internet :) }

Comment: @Fattie I added to my solution since you added a bounty, I still don't think using string for a key path is worth it. You can do everything with `WritableKeyPath` and generics.

Comment: Cheers @loremipsum yes I clicked a bounty since your original answer was so helpful.  (Regarding the addendum of using a dictionary, there are (of course) innumerable alternative approaches whether core data, sql, blah. Certainly in many cases a dictionary is fine. Trivially using string comparison is fine and keeps your types as you wish. Approach would depend on your performance milieu.)  The actual answer to the question is just "No" in current swift, thanks for clearing that up! (reflection approach really no different than just typing string comparisons by hand, just saves you typing!)

Answer (score 1):

With `struct` you have `KeyPath` and `WritableKeyPath`. As written your `Server` is only compatible with `KeyPath` because all your properties are `let`.

```
print(x[keyPath: \.dogs])
```

If you change your properties to make them mutable `var` you can use.

```
struct Server: Codable {
    var cats: Int
    var dogs: Int
    var fishies: Int
}

var x = Server(cats: 42, dogs: 13, fishies: 777)

print(x[keyPath: \.dogs])

x[keyPath: \.fishies] = 888

print(x)
```

If you insist on using `String` you can use `Codable` and `JSONSerialization` but it is a bad idea and counter to type safe principle because any of it could fail at any point with no warning.

```
extension Server {
    subscript(_ keyPath: String) -> Any? {
        get {
            if let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(self)
                , var dict = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String: Any] { //Any of this could fail silently at any time
                return dict[keyPath]
            } else {
                return nil
            }
        }
        set {
            if let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(self)
                , var dict = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String: Any] { //Any of this could fail silently at any time
                dict[keyPath] = newValue
                
                if let newData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dict), let newObj = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Self.self, from: newData) { //Any of this could fail silently at any time
                    self = newObj
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Something like this will now work

```
x["fishies"] = 777

print("\(x["fishies"])")
```

But if there is a type issue

```
x["fishies"] = "some string"

print("\(x["fishies"])")
```

You won't know about it.

You can put the `subscript` in a `protocol` and reuse it for anything.

```
struct Server: TerribleProtocol {
    var cats: Int
    var dogs: Int
    var fishies: Int
}
protocol TerribleProtocol: Codable{}

extension TerribleProtocol {
    subscript(_ keyPath: String) -> Any? {
```

Comment: Lorem, thanks for that great explanation of the keyPath syntax of which I had no clue. Based on your great answer I clarified the question, TY.

Comment: @Fattie I answered the question as asked. You wanted to use key paths I used key paths. I don’t think there is a way to use string but it is unnecessary and smelly. Why use strings when they are so prone to bugs. Generics can solve just about anything a string can do. You can probably make a quick macro for this though.

Comment: This library for example seems to do it - https://github.com/wickwirew/Runtime

Comment: They seem to be using reflexion. That is waaayyy more involved than this. Doable but way more involved. Just use their product. You asked about key paths I provided an answer that uses key paths.